# How to merge a few lists?

Tags: java, collections, merge

How to combine three lists:

```
  List<String> one = Arrays.asList("one","four","seven");
    List<String> two = Arrays.asList("two","five","eight");
    List<String> three = Arrays.asList("three","six");

    List<List<String>> merged = ...;
```

To get in result this:

```
List {one, two, three, four, five , six , seven, eight}
```

In real case I need get some queue of matches, from lists (groups) of participants. That in first match play all first participants from different groups. In second match play all second participants and so on. And I will not be able to sort it out.

Comment: Have you tried to use the addAll(...) method on the lists?

Comment: @Lukas Werner Just adAll() few times and Collection.sort is incorrect.

Comment: How come merged list is not of String but of List<List<String>>... Check your definitions

Comment: could you be more precise. How exactly do you want to merge/sort?

Comment: "Four" is missing from your expected results?

Comment: Do want sorting? Or do you want all the first elements first, all the second elements second, all the third elements third, and so on? If the latter, your example is confusing.

Comment: @ Basil Bourque. I need get some queue of mathes, from lists (groups) of participent. That in first match play all first participents from different groups. In second math play all second participents.And so on. 

 And I will not be able to sort it out.

Comment: @ Basil Bourque "Four" is missing from your expected results? - just edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to combine the lists without altering their order, then you can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> one = Arrays.asList("one","four","seven");
    List<String> two = Arrays.asList("two","five","eight");
    List<String> three = Arrays.asList("three","six");

    System.out.println(zipLists(one, two, three)); 
    //[one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight]
}

public static List<String> zipLists(List<String>... lists) {
    int maxSize = 0, totalSize = 0;
    List<Iterator<String>> iterators = new ArrayList<>(lists.length);
    for(List<String> list: lists) {
        int size = list.size();
        maxSize = Math.max(maxSize, size);
        totalSize += size;
        iterators.add(list.iterator());
    }
    List<String> mergedList = new ArrayList<>(totalSize);
    for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
        for(Iterator<String> iterator: iterators) {
            if(iterator.hasNext()) {
                mergedList.add(iterator.next());
            }
        }
    }
    return mergedList;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is realy what i need. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Java 8 streams to easily merge your lists together and `flatMap()` it to a single `List` of `String`. Sorting by "one", "two", "three" etc. will require a custom sorter because simply sorting by String.compareTo() or any other natural sort will do lexical comparison of characters, not their meanings in English.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Merge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> one = Arrays.asList("one","four","seven");
        List<String> two = Arrays.asList("two","five","eight");
        List<String> three = Arrays.asList("three","six");

        List<List<String>> merged = Arrays.asList(one, two, three);
        System.out.println(merged);
        // Output -> [[one, four, seven], [two, five, eight], [three, six]]

        List<String> flatMapped = merged.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(flatMapped);
        // Output -> [one, four, seven, two, five, eight, three, six]

        flatMapped.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            // TODO - implement sorting logic to return "one", "two", "three", etc.
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two points:
- You cannot sort number words, written in Strings by the number. Therefore you have to do some mapping, e.g. with a Map, which is then sort by keys or you write a Comparator for the sort method
- Arrays.asList(...) generates a unmodifiable list, you cannot add something to it

So, this works for me:

```
List<String> one = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("one", "four", "seven"));
List<String> two = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("two", "five", "eight"));
List<String> three = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("three", "six", "ten"));

one.addAll(two);
one.addAll(three);

one.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    // Declare here, which value is less, equal or greater than the other

    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By default, when you sort a list of `String`'s, they will be sorted in lexicographic order (a-z, 0-9, etc.), and thus you cannot expect `Collections.sort` to sort your list of `String`'s in the order that you expect.

Thus you will need to implement a custom `Comparator` that can do what want, and use the method signature `Collections.sort(list, yourCustomComparator)`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all you want to do is take elements from the source lists one at a time and 'weave' them in with the other lists...
Recursive solution:

```
public static List<String> MergeLists (List<List<String>> a2 ) {
    List<String> h = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<List<String>> a = new ArrayList<List<String>>(); 
    boolean call = false;
    for (List<String> l : a2) {
        if (! l.isEmpty()) {
            h.add(l.get(0));
            if (l.size() > 0) {
                a.add((List<String>) l.subList(1, l.size()));
                call = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (call) { h.addAll(MergeLists(a)); return h;}
    else return h;
}
```